# How large of a String should generally be stored in one core data entity attribute?

Tags: ios, core-data, attributes, entity

How large of a `String` should generally be stored in one `core data` `entity` `attribute`?

At what point should the `String` be broken into multiple `attributes` or even multiple `entities` with relationships?

---

I don't know how space-dense `Strings` are. Imagine wanting to save text from 100 pages into 1 `attribute`: `String`.

Other than difficulties of `Querying Core Data` for specific `attributes`, would this cause any problems?

**Basically, how large of a `String` would be too large to store as an attribute?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use one attribute or multiple attributes depends only on whether the data is logically a single value or multiple values. That is, it depends entirely on the structure of the data, not its size.

However, for excessively large values, it often makes more sense to save the data in a separate file and keep only the file name in Core Data. When you need the full value, get the file name from Core Data and load the file contents.

The advantage of this approach is that you avoid reading the entire value into memory when you don't need it-- for example, getting the entire 100 page string value in memory when you only care about other fields (like a "title" field or something). Splitting the data into multiple attributes doesn't fix this problem and creates extra, unnecessary complexity.

Comment: at what point is the "entire value (read) into memory"? Only when casting the `object` as an `entity` and calling one of their  `.attributes`? Or are all `.attributes(values)` read to memory when FetchRequesting these `entity`?

Comment: it must be when the fetchRequest happens

Comment: It depends how you configure the fetch. In the most common use, the fetch returns fault objects whose property values haven't been loaded yet. Accessing one property loads all of them. There are various ways to alter this behavior-- see `NSFetchRequest` documentation. To avoid accidentally loading unwanted properties, use `NSDictionaryResultType` and `propertiesToFetch`.